# Повернутое изображение во ImageView после снимка кастомной камерой в Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, android-camera

Привет. Я делаю снимок в андроид приложении кастомной камерой

```
camera = Camera.open(0);
```

После чего поварачиваю ее что бы сохранить

```
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                Camera.getCameraInfo(CAMERA_ORIENTATION, info);
                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                int degrees = 0;

                    switch (rotation) {
                        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                            degrees = 0;
                            break; //Natural orientation
                        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                            degrees = 90;
                            break; //Landscape left
                        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                            degrees = 180;
                            break;//Upside down
                        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                            degrees = 270;
                            break;//Landscape right
                    }


                int rotate = ( info.orientation - degrees + 360 ) % 360;

                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                params.setRotation(rotate);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

И сохраняю

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

Все как по учебнику...

Если смотреть через галерею, или проводник то проблем никаких нет, все хорошо и красиво... Но если я пытаюсь последнее изображение вывести в ImageView то получаю картинку повернутую на -90 градусов если снять вертикально, и -180 если горизонтально на правом боку, в случае с левым наклоном все нормально...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
        myPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Собственно сам вывод...

Если же я использую  `Picasso` то все нормально, но у меня в задаче есть момент рисования по фото, для чего и нужен Bitmap... 
Подскажите в какую сторону копать? Спасибо!)

Comment: Вам нужно читать exif данные из файла изображения и поворачивать его перед установкой в ImageView. Галерея и Picasso это и делают. P.S. С помощью Picasso можно получить и Bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/a/34390998/3069565

Comment: @eugeneek Спасибо! все оказалось довольно таки просто!)

Comment: Напишите ответ, как вы это решили. Будет полезно другим участникам сообщества

Answer (score 1):

Собственно вот и все решение. Может кому то поможет.

```
File file;
Bitmap bitmap;

void showPhoto(String url){

   file = new File(url);

   try {
       ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
       int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
       int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       if (rotation != 0f) {matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);}
           bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    }catch(IOException ex){
        Log.e("LOG EXIF", "Failed to get Exif data", ex);
    }

   myPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
     if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; }
     else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; }
     else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }
     return 0;
}
```